# How to calculate TextBox height

Tags: vb.net

I would like to add TextBox controls to a form automatically at run time when the form is resized. However, I only want to add them of the form has grown enough vertically to accommodate the height of new TextBox.

Is there way to calculate the height of the text box if I know the font family and font size?

Comment: Just look at the height of an existing TextBox control.  Presumably they all use the same font.

Comment: That size is returned by [TextBoxBase.PreferredHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.preferredheight) (which is also DPI-Aware). It's mainly defined by the current Font, but It includes the TextBox Border, if any. You probably also need to calculate the `Margin` value and the distance between controls (unless it's governed by the margins). You should give an idea of what the layout looks like, if you're using some specific container (FlowLayoutPanel or similar) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just render your textbox and check its height?

```
Dim Height= TextBox.Height
```

If you dont want your textbox to show up while checking its height you can hide it as well

```
TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
```